# /scan topic comes from a camera node rather than the desired LiDAR node

Tags: navigation, ros-kinetic, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys. I'm trying to use a rplidar to run amcl navigation with my pre-built map on Turtlebot2, ROS Kinetic. Below is my amcl launch file:

```
<launch>
  <!-- Define laser type-->
  <arg name="laser_sensor" default="$(env TURTLEBOT_LASER_SENSOR)" />
  <!-- <arg name="laser_sensor" default="rplidar" /> -->

  <!-- laser driver -->
  <include file="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/laser/driver/$(arg laser_sensor)_laser.launch" />
  
  <!-- Map server -->
  <arg name="map_file" default="$(env TURTLEBOT_MAP_FILE)"/>
  <node name="map_server" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" args="$(arg map_file)" />

  <!-- AMCL -->
  <arg name="custom_amcl_launch_file" default="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/launch/includes/amcl/$(arg laser_sensor)_amcl.launch.xml"/>
  <arg name="initial_pose_x" default="0.0"/> <!-- Use 17.0 for willow's map in simulation -->
  <arg name="initial_pose_y" default="0.0"/> <!-- Use 17.0 for willow's map in simulation -->
  <arg name="initial_pose_a" default="0.0"/>
  <include file="$(arg custom_amcl_launch_file)">
    <arg name="initial_pose_x" value="$(arg initial_pose_x)"/>
    <arg name="initial_pose_y" value="$(arg initial_pose_y)"/>
    <arg name="initial_pose_a" value="$(arg initial_pose_a)"/>
  </include>

  <!-- Move base -->
  <arg name="custom_param_file" default="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/param/$(arg laser_sensor)_costmap_params.yaml"/>
  <include file="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/launch/includes/rplidar_move_base.launch.xml">
    <arg name="custom_param_file" value="$(arg custom_param_file)"/>
  </include>

</launch>
```

where the "laser_sensor" is rplidar. But the weird thing is that when I ran this launch file, the `/scan` topic came from a camera node rather than the pre-defined rplidar node. [Here](https://imgur.com/a/Zn28F85) is the rqt_graph. I have no idea why this happened. I don't even equip the turtlebot2 with a camera. Could someone explain how to fix it? I really appreciate your help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/410342//scan-topic-comes-from-a-camera-node-rather-than-the-desired-lidar-node/) by [RockAndROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/101146/rockandros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2022-12-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2022-12-10**:
Why is line 4 commented out? This will make all the `$(arg laser_sensor)` vars expand to an empty string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks for your kind attention. Here I actually have defined the `laser_sensor` as the desired LiDAR in `~/.bashrc`, so it should be okay. Finally I found that the reason for this problem is that another guy who previously borrowed my robot created a new workspace, which contains a package with the same name as mine, even the launch file inside. And when I input `roslaunch [package_name] [launch_file_name]`, somehow it is his launch file that is executed by default. I think maybe `roslaunch [launch_file_path]` is more reliable. What a coincidence! Thank you again for your reply!

---

Originally posted by [RockAndROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/101146/rockandros/) with karma: 16 on 2022-12-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0